# Data masking in AKHQ

Tags: apache-kafka, data-masking, akhq

I am using akhq for visualization with kafka. I have some attributes in my records that need to be masked in akhq. I used data masking configuration (from documentation : https://akhq.io/docs/configuration/akhq.html#data-masking), but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the configuration in application.yml

```
akhq:
  security:
    data-masking:
      filters:
        - description: "Masks value for secret-key fields"
          search-regex: '"(secret-key)":".*"'
          replacement: '"$1":"xxxx"'
```

I still get the value of the secret-key.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QPBd.png)